# Very small estimate in linear regresion

Tags: r, linear-regression

So I am trying to make a linear regression between two variables, the independent variable being "year" and the dependent one "price". So I am trying to determine the influence year has on the price. I am making a linear regression in R like this:

```
model_price_Year <- lm(data = audi, price ~ year)
summary(model_price_Year)
```

And i get the following results:

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -6.437e+06  8.503e+04  -75.71   <2e-16 
year         3.203e+03  4.215e+01   75.98   <2e-16
```

Can the estimate value be that small? Is it correct? And how do i interpret it?

Comment: Look up "scientific notation"

Comment: The value if the estiamte is interpreted as an increment in the dependent variable **per unit** of the independent variable. In your case: The estimate says that per year there is an increase of `3.203e+03 = 3203` units in your dependent variable `price`.

Comment: Oh I understand now. But can i make it so it shows the value without "e"? To show just 3203.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimates aren't small:
6.437e+06=6437000
3.203e+03=3203

If you don't want scientific notation, simply put `options(scipen = 9999)` at the beginning of your script.